# convert bean xml to spring boot annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following bean xml from spring framework. Now we are moving to spring boot with all annotations. How do I convert the following bean to annotations ?

```
<bean id="testPool" class="com.v1.testPoolImpl" init-method="init" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <property name="configurations">
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
            <property name="location" value="classpath:database.properties"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

com.v1.testPoolImpl (is some other library)

Answer (score 4):

You can create new `Configuration` class.
You can rewrite `<bean>` with annotation `@Bean` and for then create `new` instance of class and using setters you set variables.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean(initMethod = "init" , destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public Object testPool(){
        testPoolImpl testPool = new testPoolImpl();
        PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation( new ClassPathResource("database.properties"));
        propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        testPool.setConfigurations(propertiesFactoryBean.getObject());

        return testPool;
    }
}
```

Comment: `testPool.setConfigurations(propertiesFactoryBean);` should be `testPool.setConfigurations(propertiesFactoryBean.getObject())` and before that you should call the `propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet()` method to honor the lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

With Spring boot, you can specify properties file through command-line when running jar file, using command:

```
java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/another-location.properties
```

Alternatively, you can mention property files using @PropertySource Annotation on javaConfig file. So, it would be something like this:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:my-app.properties")
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {
    //...
}
```

Hope this helps.